# Unable to start Chrome Driver in Selenium Webdriver 2

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to open Chrome browser from Selenium webdriver but I'm failing to do so. At first I tried opening both Chrome and Firefox from the same program. The Firefox browser works perfectly fine, while I got error related to ChromeDriver exe file being not present. I downloaded the ChromeDriver file and added that to the External Jars and also called it using the `System.setProperty(` method.

Here is the original code:

```
package test.selenium;

import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
public class Selenium_test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    FirefoxDriver dr1=new FirefoxDriver();
    FirefoxDriver dr2=new FirefoxDriver();

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://chromedriver.exe");

    ChromeDriver dr3=new ChromeDriver();
    ChromeDriver dr4=new ChromeDriver();


    dr1.get("http://google.com");
    dr2.get("http://northeastraveller.com");

    dr3.get("http://quora.com");
    dr4.get("http://facebook.com");
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

I separated the Chrome part into a separate program named "Chrome_test", whose code is as follows

```
package test.selenium;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

 public class Chrome_Test{

 public static void main(String[] args) {


  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://chromedriver.exe");

    ChromeDriver dr3=new ChromeDriver();
    ChromeDriver dr4=new ChromeDriver();

    dr3.get("http://quora.com");
    dr4.get("http://facebook.com");
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

Now I'm getting the following error :

**Error: Could not find or load main class test.selenium.Chrome_Test**

I checked the classpath variables and all seems to be at place. What am I missing here?

Comment: The 'error' is stating it can't find your Class nothing to do with not finding the chromedriver. Did you create an archive or something and forgot to add you main class to the Manifest? Maybe you forgot to add the local ( . ) path to your java argument.

Comment: Can you explain this further. I don't think I did something like this.

Comment: Can it happen because I'm using Win-7 64 bit? Because there is no 64-bit driver for ChromeDriver in the api link given google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You better place two backward slashes like:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe");
```

It will work.

Comment: this should be in comment, not as separate answer

Comment: i don't have reputation to post a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Change the chrome driver properties line with backslashes (\) and it would work.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe");
```

Comment: Sorry didn't work on my code. Looks like something else is wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote code which downloads and installs the latest [`ChromeDriver`](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/) automatically to the project root directory if none has been found. That way you can receive a `ChromeDriver` instance without actually worrying about the `chromedriver.exe` file. Feel free to adjust it to your needs. You still need to include [`Selenium` libraries](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java) in your project though. For my `ChromeDriverFactory` class below you also need [`Apache Commons IO`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io/2.4) and [`Zip4J`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.lingala.zip4j/zip4j).

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import net.lingala.zip4j.core.ZipFile;
import net.lingala.zip4j.exception.ZipException;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class ChromeDriverFactory
{
    private static String chromeDriverRepository = "http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/";

    public static WebDriver getChromeDriver() throws MalformedURLException,
            IOException, ZipException
    {
        String chromeDriverFileName = "chromedriver.exe";
        File chromeDriverFile = new File(chromeDriverFileName);

        if (!chromeDriverFile.exists())
        {
            installChromeDriver();
        }

        setChromeDriverProperty(chromeDriverFileName);

        return new ChromeDriver();
    }

    private static void setChromeDriverProperty(String chromeDriverFileName)
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromeDriverFileName);
    }

    private static void installChromeDriver() throws IOException,
            MalformedURLException, ZipException
    {
        String newestVersion = getNewestVersion();
        String targetFile = "chromedriver_win32.zip";
        String downloadUrl = chromeDriverRepository + newestVersion + "/"
                + targetFile;
        String downloadFileName = FilenameUtils.getName(downloadUrl);
        File downloadFile = new File(downloadFileName);
        String projectRootDirectory = System.getProperty("user.dir");

        FileUtils.copyURLToFile(new URL(downloadUrl), downloadFile);

        ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(downloadFile);
        zipFile.extractAll(projectRootDirectory);
        FileUtils.deleteQuietly(downloadFile);
    }

    private static String getNewestVersion() throws MalformedURLException,
            IOException
    {
        String newestVersionUrl = chromeDriverRepository + "LATEST_RELEASE";
        InputStream input = new URL(newestVersionUrl).openStream();

        return IOUtils.toString(input);
    }
}
```